# How to update a value in a HTML file using Python?

Tags: python, html, css, serial-communication

I'm receiving data from an Arduino,parsing it using Python and my intent is to update the values in the HTML using the data from serial. Like `<h6>value</h6>`so the new value will be there when I refresh the page. How to do it?

Comment: What is the result when it is parsed?

Comment: 4 variables with numeric values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your situation but, We use python as the server-side language and for making a dynamic HTML, we use Django Template which is developed for Django (A python based framework).
Here's an example of making a simple html with some data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="keywords" content="{{ meta.keywords }}" />
  <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true"/>

  <title>{{ meta.title}}</title>
  <meta name="description" content="{{ meta.description }}">
  <meta name="og:description" content="{{ meta.description }}">
  <meta property="og:title" content="{{ meta.title }}" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="{{ meta.image_url}}" />
  <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>{{ data.title }}</h1>

  <h2>{{ data.description }}</h2>

  {% if data.additional_info %}
   <p>
    {{ data.additional_info }}
   </p>
  {% endif %}

  {% if data.list1|length > 0  %}
   {% for item in data.list1 %}
    <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
    <p>
     {{ item.content }}
    </p>
   {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}

 {% if data.list2|length > 0  %}
   {% for item in data.list2 %}
    <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
    <p>
      {{ item.content }}
    </p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{% if data.list3|length > 0  %}
  {% for item in data.list3 %}
    <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
    <p>
       {{ item.content }}
    </p>
   {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So say like I want to upload some images my website's folder, this html file can detect how many images are in there and display the correct number of images?